# How to assign the strings from temp to returnString?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

The goal is to reverse the string current. I know there's easier and more efficient ways to reverse a string, but we had to come up with our own method for an assignment.

`temp` is assigned the last character in the string, then the second to last, then the third to last etc., one at a time. I need to figure out how to assign these individual strings to `returnString` in the reverse order of the original string.

```
String current = "Reverse this string.";
String returnString;
for (int i = 1; i <= current.length(); ++i) {
    String temp = current.substring(current.length() - i, current.length() - i + 1);
    returnString = ??? 
}
```

Comment: `returnString += temp;` would do it, but it would be inefficient. I'd recommend using a `StringBuilder`

Comment: I don't think that efficiency is what he's looking for. Just functionality

Comment: Why not use `String.charAt()`? Or is that part of the "easier and more efficient ways" that you do not want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start with an empty String, so:

```
String returnString = "";
```

Then append the string `temp` to it:

```
returnString = returnString + temp;
```

The `+` operator concatenates Strings.

There is a shorthand for `x = x + a`: `x += a`, so you could write:

```
returnString += temp;
```

Note that this is inefficient, as a new String is created each time you use the `+` or `+=` -- you would get a more efficient solution with a `StringBuilder`, because it has a buffer of characters which it modifies as you append, rather than creating brand new buffers inside String objects.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it (still inefficient):

```
String current = "Reverse this string.";
String returnString = "";
for (char c : current.toCharArray()) {
    returnString = Character.toString(c) + returnString;
}
```

This works by taking each character from the input string in order and adding it to the start of the resulting string. Thus eventually, the final character of the input is added to the beginning of the output.

For example:

```
Input: "abc"

Loop 1:
    returnString = "a"

Loop 2:
    returnString = "ba"

Loop 3:
    returnString = "cba"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just using arrays

```
    String current = "Reverse this string.";
    char c[] = current.toCharArray();
    char out[] = new char[c.length];

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = c.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        out[index++] = c[i];
    }
    String str = new String (out);
    System.out.println(str);
```

**output**

```
.gnirts siht esreveR
```